# while export data from phpmyadmin its return to sql query page

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I run below query on phpMyAdmin
I got data but while click on export it redirects to sql query tab

```sql
Select
    sad.firstname,
    sad.lastname,
    sfo.base_total_invoiced,
    sad.email,
    sad.telephone,
    sad.postcode,
    sad.street,
    sad.locality,
    sad.city
From
    sales_flat_order_address sad
Inner join
    customer_address_entity cae ON sad.entity_id = cae.entity_id
Inner join
    pincode_24_11_2015 pc ON sad.postcode = pc.pincode
Inner join
    pincode_city_state_map pcs ON pc.pincode_id = pcs.pincode_id
Inner join
    city c on pcs.city_id = c.city_id
Inner join
    sales_flat_order sfo on sad.entity_id = sfo.entity_id
Where
    sad.city = "Pune" 
And
    cae.created_at Between "2015-01-01 00:00:00" And "2016-01-07 00:00:00";
```

can somebody help on this.

Comment: You can export, and also export results. Click on that and it will give you options to format your export. Such as .sql, .csv whatever.

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Remove table aliases (use real table names)

```
SELECT
    sales_flat_order_address.firstname,
    sales_flat_order_address.lastname,
    sales_flat_order.base_total_invoiced,
    sales_flat_order_address.email,
    sales_flat_order_address.telephone,
    sales_flat_order_address.postcode,
    sales_flat_order_address.street,
    sales_flat_order_address.locality,
    sales_flat_order_address.city
FROM sales_flat_order_address
INNER JOIN customer_address_entity
    ON sales_flat_order_address.entity_id = customer_address_entity.entity_id
INNER JOIN pincode_24_11_2015
    ON sales_flat_order_address.postcode = pincode_24_11_2015.pincode
INNER JOIN pincode_city_state_map
    ON pincode_24_11_2015.pincode_id = pincode_city_state_map.pincode_id
INNER JOIN city
    ON pincode_city_state_map.city_id = city.city_id
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order
    ON sales_flat_order_address.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id
WHERE sales_flat_order_address.city = "Pune" 
    AND customer_address_entity.created_at BETWEEN "2015-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-01-07 00:00:00";
```